# Azure AAD user Access token generation without Client_secret

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-app-registration

I am trying to generate access token for user using the API https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/token
with below body parameters

client_id, grant_type(= password), resource, username and password.

for one clientId, i am able to get access token with above params. but for a second Client_id, it fails with message "AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret". It works only when i pass the client_secret for my second app.

how should I configure/create the second AppId/Client_id, so that i can generate the access token without specifying client_secret.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

I created an Azure AD Application and generated access token via **Postman** by providing parameters like below and got the **same error** as below:

```json
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/token

client_id : xxxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx
grant_type : password
resource : resource
username : ruk@********.onmicrosoft.com
password : ******
```

[image]

Please **note** that, **`client_secret`** is required for the ROPC flow when the Azure AD Application is not a public client.

You can create **`client_secret`** if you do not want your Azure AD Application as public client.

***To resolve the error, enable `Allow public client flows setting` in your Azure AD Application like below:***

*Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> App Registrations -> Your App -> Authentication -> Allow public client flows -> YES*

[image]

**I am able to get the access token successfully without **`client_secret`** like below:**

[image]